# Updating JPanel after selecting an option from JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Just out of curiosity, is it possible to display different content on the same frame depending on the option selected from a JComboBox?

For example, if I have the following options in a JComboBox: `Fruits, Vegetables`, Upon selecting `fruits` from the JComboBox, an empty JPanel will automatically display different kinds of fruits, and similar idea for the vegetables.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Just have the listener for the combo box change your panel however you would like. If you're just displaying an image consider looking at jLabel and setting the image of the label based on selection.

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for a working example that displays an image based on the item selected in the combo box.